# Selecting the last general sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a bunch of divs with class B following a div with class A:

```
<div class="B"></div>
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="A"></div>

<div class="B"></div>
<div class="A"></div>
```

I'm trying to apply a CSS rule to the last A after each B. I tried

```
.B ~ .A:last-of-type
```

but that didn't work. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you post a simple HTML file demonstrating the problem?  What browser did you test?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 33. Here's a jsfiddle with what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/GtLWJ/. last-of-type only underlines the bottom set, not both sets.

Comment: There is no previous sibling selector for CSS. You'll probably need to reorganize the HTML or use JS to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently do this with css. The `:last-of-type` pseudo class works with element types such as `span` `div` etc - not with classes

Being that:

1) There is no currently no previous sibling selector

2) You can't change the structure of your markup and

3) You don't know in advance how many .A divs you have after each .B div ...

... you're out luck, CSS currently can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:last-of-type` selector in this case.

```
.A:last-of-type {
/*apply styling */
}
```

In your case I recommend you to group them in divs. http://jsfiddle.net/GtLWJ/
This works.

```
 <div class="sec1">
<div class="head">Set</div>
<div class="sub">Item 1</div>
<div class="sub">Item 2</div>
<div class="sub">Item 3</div>
</div>
<div  class="sec1">
<div class="head">Set</div>
<div class="sub">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .head {
    font-weight: 800;
}

.sec1 .sub:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the structure.